# Changing which libc.so gets linked?

Tags: c, gcc, mips, ld

Im trying to cross compile for MIPSEL on my router. I got stuff working in assembly, but now Im moving to trying to compile basic C code.

Currently just have simple hello world c code, and using the mipsel-linux-gnu-gcc compiler, which works for assembly.

Compiler command:

```
 mipsel-linux-gnu-gcc  -L/home/uname/devel/extr/squashfs-root/lib -l:libc.so.0 -mips32 -Wl,--build-id=none -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/lib/ld-uClibc.so.0  ma.c
```

The libc.so.0 is extracted from the firmware for the router.

The program compiles, however in readelf, the issue is that it links against libc.so.6

```
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libc.so.6]
```

whereas pulling the busybox binary from the firmware and running readelf on it

```
0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libc.so.0]
```

How do I get it to link against libc.so.0?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to negate the standard glibc path, as the compiler checks this first. This can be done by compiling with `-nostdinc`.

You'll then need to `-I` include the gcc headers and such, as discussed [here.](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Glibc2-HOWTO-6.html)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Had to build a uClibc toolchain using buildroot.